Consistent initialisation in simple DAE system using GEKKO
I'm messing around with GEKKO for dynamic simulations to see how it compares to commercial simulation software e.g. gPROMS.
As a simple test I'm attempting to model the blowdown of a pressurised vessel. However I cannot seem to get the solver to consistently initialise the simulation.
I have modelled the system using the following system of DAE's
dM/dt = -outlet_flowrate (1)
outlet_flowrate = f(Pressure,Outlet_Pressure) (2)
Pressure = f(M,T) (3)

Where Outlet_Pressure is fixed at a value, T is fixed at a value. I expect that I can specify the initial mass (M), the initial pressure could then be calculated  using equation (3) , the initial outlet flowrate can then be calculated using equation (2).
I have used arbitrary function for f(Pressure,Outlet_pressure) and f(M,T) to simplify the model as a minimum reproducible example:
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)

mass = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100)
Outlet_flowrate = m.Var(lb=0,ub=10000000)
pressure = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1000000)

m.Equation(mass.dt() == -Outlet_flowrate)
m.Equation(Outlet_flowrate == (pressure-2))
m.Equation(pressure == mass*2)

m.free_initial(pressure)
m.free_initial(Outlet_flowrate)

m.options.IMODE=4
m.options.RTOL=1e-15
m.solve()

plt.plot(m.time,pressure.value)
print(pressure.value)
plt.show()

However when I attempt to solve this model I get the following output from the solver:
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  0
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  3
   Intermediates:  0
   Connections  :  2
   Equations    :  3
   Residuals    :  3

 Number of state variables:    398
 Number of total equations: -  396
 Number of slack variables: -  0
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :    2

 @error: Degrees of Freedom
 * Error: DOF must be zero for this mode
 STOPPING...

I have tried solving the model using IMODE=7 which does solve the model however this initialises the pressure at 0. I think the initial mass should be sufficient to specify the initial pressure at 4 not zero.
I am aware that I can trivially reduce the model to remove pressure and flowrate as variabes, however in the future I would like to apply this methodology to other systems which aren't as trivial to reduce. I'm also aware that I could specify the initial pressure by manually computing the initial pressure from the initial mass.
Is manually computing the initial condition something that most people do or have I missed a method in GEKKO to calculate the initial values of these variables ?
Thanks

The first node of a dynamic simulation is deactivated in Gekko because initial conditions are typically fixed. Gekko doesn't require consistent initial condition and can solve higher-index DAEs without Pantelides algorithm (differentiate higher-order algebraic equations to return to ODE or index-1 DAE form). There is no easy way to undo this default behavior. As an alternative, a small time step (e.g. 1e-10) can be placed at the beginning to calculate the correct initial condition of variables solved with algebraic equations.

from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = np.linspace(0,20,100)
m.time = np.insert(m.time,1,1e-10)

mass = m.Var(value=2,lb=0,ub=100)
Outlet_flowrate = m.Var(lb=0,ub=10000000)
pressure = m.Var(lb=0,ub=1000000)

m.Equation(mass.dt() == -Outlet_flowrate)
m.Equation(Outlet_flowrate == (pressure-2))
m.Equation(pressure == mass*2)

m.options.IMODE=4
m.options.SOLVER=1
m.solve()

plt.plot(m.time[1:],pressure.value[1:])
print(pressure.value)
plt.show()

The first time point is removed from the results with:
plt.plot(m.time[1:],pressure.value[1:])

The initial conditions are removed and the results are numerically the same if the initial time step is small enough.
